# Docker bind mount usage

Tags: docker, data-binding, docker-volume

Our application is running on a unix box(let's say box1) on which one nfs filer is mounted on `/var/app/data` directory.

Application writes some text file on the mounted directory `/var/app/data`.

Our downstream application (running on some other unix box) will read these files as they are present on nfs filer. We are planning to migrate our application to docker.

I am thinking to use bind-mount feature as it will allow me to map host machine(box1) directory `/var/app/data` to any directory in container.

However I have found most blogs suggesting to use volumes over bind-mount.
can someone please how to use volume mount in my scenario as upto my understanding, we can not mention source directory (`/var/app/data` in my case) while creating the volume.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/#populate-a-volume-using-a-container):

1. Create a docker volume: `docker volume create my_vol`
2. Mount the volume in a container: `docker run -d -v my_vol:/destination_with_content -n my_container busybox`
3. Populate it with the data you want: `docker cp /var/app/data my_container:/destination_with_content`
4. Now you can run the container you want and pass the populated volume: `docker run -d -v my_vol:/destination_new_container my_image`

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Physical location for volume my_vol will be different from /var/app/data as physical location will be manged by docker itself. Above steps are basically sharing the data present in /var/app/data folder to the container so that application can use that from /destination_with_content. But what about the data being generated by my application. Application running in container will not  write access to /var/app/data(present on host).

Comment: I think that's exactly the difference between docker named volumes and bind mounts. Named volumes: docker decides where it puts the data on the host. This is a good thing when running docker in a cluster and using e.g. volume plugins. It makes your cluster host agnostic bc you don't have to know anything about the directory structure of the host(s) bc you don't have to put a specific directory anywhere in your code (bc docker itself handles where it can find the directory for a specific volume). A bind mount is the opposite. You have to know the directory on the host and bind it explicitly.