# Using a Bind Mount in Docker to have a folder on Windows Host Machine available to Container

Tags: windows, docker

I'm trying to get a setup where I can deploy a Docker Container with a java app installed on it where the app can write to a folder in the container and for those files to appear on the host machine.

I believe that a `--mount` with `type=bind` is the correct solution for this.  However, I cannot seem to get the mount to show up when I run `docker inspect MyContainer`.

My full setup is as follows;

Docker File:

```
FROM openjdk:14.0.2-jdk-nanoserver

WORKDIR /monitor

COPY target/monitor.jar ./

ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "monitor.jar"] --restart unless-stopped
```

Build Command:

`docker build -t monitor .`

and my Run command:

`docker run --restart unless-stopped --name MonitorContainer monitor --mount type=bind,source=C:/test,target=/monitor`

With the above, I'm attempting to have the folder `C:/test` available for read and write inside the container at the path `/monitor`.  However, when I run `docker inspect StreamMonitorContainer` I see that the mount section is empty so it appears the mount is not created.

I receive no errors, so it's all rather confusing.

I would appreciate any help, I'm completely novice at this so please be nice :)

p.s.  This question differs from [Docker bind mount usage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55569932/docker-bind-mount-usage) because it's dealing with Volumes, not Bind Mounts (despite the title.)

Comment: Docker options like `--mount` need to come _before_ the image name `monitor`.  If you look at what gets passed to your application's `main()` function you will see the options are getting passed in to the application, not being handled by Docker.

Comment: @DavidMaze That has brought me closer to a solution, however, I'm getting an error `docker: Error response from daemon: invalid mount config for type "bind": invalid mount path: '/monitor'.` now.  No matter what path I try it just says it's invalid...?  Is there something else I'm missing there?

Comment: @DavidMaze Interesting... an absolute path DOES work.  Got there in the end :D  Thanks for the help!  I now get a proper mount in the `inspect` output :)  You could perhaps provide your comment as an answer - it solved my problem!  (Worth mentioning I needed an absolute path also...)